# Backfilling aggregate data in SQL(Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a query that aggregates on a daily basis data over different time periods 1/3/7/14/30/60 days.

Looks something like this:

```
SELECT REGION, CUSTOMER, SYSDATE AS SNAPSHOT_DAY
, COUNT (CASE WHEN HIT_DAY >= SYSDATE -60 THEN SESSION END ) AS D60_SESSS_CNT
, COUNT (CASE WHEN HIT_DAY >= SYSDATE -30 THEN SESSION END ) AS D30_SESSS_CNT
, COUNT (CASE WHEN HIT_DAY >= SYSDATE -14 THEN SESSION END ) AS D14_SESSS_CNT
, COUNT (CASE WHEN HIT_DAY >= SYSDATE -7 THEN SESSION END ) AS D7_SESSS_CNT
, COUNT (CASE WHEN HIT_DAY >= SYSDATE -3 THEN SESSION END ) AS D3_SESSS_CNT
, COUNT (CASE WHEN HIT_DAY >= SYSDATE -1 THEN SESSION END ) AS D1_SESSS_CNT
```

I want to create a table with the aggregate information and I want to go back 3 months so that the table with aggregates would look something like this if you were to do `select* from table where cusomter = 1234`

```
REGION | CUSTOMER | SNAPSHOT_DAY | D60_SESSS_CNT| D30_SESSS_CNT| etc...
 1     |   1234   |     today    |    x         |      x       |  
 1     |   1234   |    yesterday |    x         |      x       |
 .
 .
 1     |   1234   |   today -90  |    x         |      x       |
```

I tried several different versions I'm not sure why nothing seems to work out.

Comment: How do they  not work?  And 60 days is more like 2 months than 3 months

Comment: The aggregates are up to 60 days, but I need to backfill the data for 90 days to look like the table below.